# How do I make a random walk step read the background image?

Tags: r, image

I'm trying to get my random walk to invoke function z on each step. Whenever the step ends on a red pixel in the background image variable CS=1. If the step ends on a black pixel then CS=0. Right now it's just a randomly generated value. Don't worry about the other stuff, I provide it for you to reproduce the issue, but those parts work fine. The critical part is variable CS in function step.prob.

Main question: How do I make the walk function read the background image?<-- solved

**New issue: I'm receiving a "subscript out of bounds" error in the step.prob() function. Why and how do I fix it?**

so far it looks like this:
[image]

You will need package EBImage, and this image saved as testmap2.png in your working directory to run this code.
[image: testmap2.png]
The code is currently:

```
library(tiff)
library("EBImage")

pic<-readImage("testmap2.png",all=TRUE,package="EBImage")
display(pic, method="raster")
dim(pic)
pic[,,1]


par(bg="black",col="black",col.axis="white",new=T)

P<-30
step.max=125
s<-step.max
pic<-readImage("testmap2.png",all=TRUE,package="EBImage")
walkW <- function(n.times=125,
               xlim=c(524058,542800),
               ylim=c(2799758,2818500),
               start=c(542800,2815550),
               stepsize=c(4000,4000)) {
display(pic, method="raster")
par(bg="black",col="black",col.axis="white",new=T)

    plot(c(0,0),type="n",xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim,
           xlab="Easting",ylab="Northing",col="white",col.lab="white")#arena 
    x <- start[1]
    y <- start[2]
    steps <- 1/c(1,2,4,8,12,16)
    steps.y <- c(steps,-steps,0)
    steps.x <- c(steps[c(1,5,6)],-steps,0)
    points(x,y,pch=16,col="green",cex=1)

for (i in 1:n.times) {
        repeat {
           xi <- stepsize[1]*sample(steps.x,1)
           yi <- stepsize[2]*sample(steps.y,1)
           newx <- x+xi
           newy <- y+yi
           if (newx>xlim[1] && newx<xlim[2] &&
               newy>ylim[1] && newy<ylim[2]) break
        }
        lines(c(x,newx),c(y,newy),col="white")
        x <- newx
        y <- newy

####the following function returns an "subscript out of bounds" error
 step.prob<-function(n.times=step.max){
CS<-pic[x,y,1]
CS.max<-1
step.num<-15
SP<-(((CS/CS.max)*(1-(step.num/step.max))+(step.num/step.max))*100)
}
z<-step.prob(1)
##end the function that returns an error
if(z>P)break
else

if(step.max){points(newx,newy,pch=16,col="yellow",cex=1)
}

 }
}
set.seed(101)
walkW(s)
```

Comment: Did you try `pic_data <- imageData(pic) ; pic_data[x, y, 1]`? If memory serves, the third value (three values) is [R, G, B]. 1 in first posititon == fully red.

Comment: @hrbrmstr argh is your "3 hours ago" before my "3 hours ago"?  (How does one tell?)

Comment: no, it was def 3 hrs ago :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A color `png` or `jpg` is just a multidimensional array for position and RGB color.

```
library(png) # same idea for EBImage 
pic<-readPNG("testmap2.png")
dim(pic) # 615 683   3 (3 for the RGB levels)
pic[1:5,1:5,1] # where is it red?
```

Returns:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    1    1
[2,]    0    0    0    1    1
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

So to test a point on the walk for red:

```
x <- 2; y <- 2
pic[x,y,1] # 0, not red

x <- 2; y <- 5
pic[x,y,1] # 1 , red
```

Comment: A fresh bioconductor install of EBImage installed fine in my 3.1.1 system.

Comment: You're right, I just misread the error from `install.packages("EBImage")` `package ‘EBImage’ is not available (for R version 3.1.0)` to mean that the package was not available for my version as opposed to not on CRAN in the first place.  If you're willing to hunt down and install from a tarball to answer an SO question then power to you.

Comment: I use other bioconductor packages, so no hunting required :-)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It solved part of my issue but I'm getting another error code now. I'm going to try and fix it, then I'll update the code above for future references.